# Checking if jsonb object has a specific value in array object

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to find all rows with a certain value in an array.
Currently use

```
select * from test 
where data -> 'systems' -> 0 ->> 'name' = 'Stardust' 
or info -> 'systems' -> 1 ->> 'name' = 'Stardust';
```

The systems array can theoretically be infinitely long.
Is there a way to say that when any element in the array contains this value the row should be returned?
The JSON data structure looks like this:

```json
{
  "systems": [
    {"host": "example.com", "name": "Stardust", "impact": 1}, 
    {"host": "example2.com", "name": "Milkyway", "impact": 0}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this :

1. If the JSON contains another JSON Object

```
select * from test where data->'systems' @> '[{"name":"Stardust"}]';
```

2. If the JSON array contains strings

```
select * from test where data->'systems' ? 'Stardust';
```

Please refer the `jsonb Operators` section [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) for more different functions you can use.

Comment: It does not seem to work for me. Look at the edit I posted about the structure of the json. Is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: Okay got it. It should be '[{"name":"Stardust"}]' not '{"name":"Stardust"}'.

Comment: yeah correct. Let me edit and update the same. I missed the brackets I think. Happy you worked it out :)

Comment: If you got the answer to your query and if you think my answer was a bit helpful then could you please mark it as answer?

Comment: This works great, thank you for putting me on the right track!